# How can I open an html & css file on my Macbook on my iPhone?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website (html & css) on my Macbook that's just on localhost.

I'm looking to be able to easily open the website on my iPhone for testing.

Does anyone have any neat ideas on how I can do this?

If this is not the right type of question to ask here would someone be so kind enough to point me to an appropriate forum?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the two devices are on the same network, make sure that the HTTP server isn't *just* listening on the loopback interface, then just replace `localhost` in the URL with the IP address or hostname of the Macbook and load that on the phone's browser.